# Find index k of element x in array in O(log(k)) time

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Studying for a test and found this problem which I'd like some help with.

The problem:

Let A = (a_1, a_2,..., a_n) be a sorted array of n distinct elements and x an element in A.

Design an O(logk)-time algorithm to compute the index k of the cell of A containing x (that is, A[k] = x).

Notice that if k = theta(n), then a standard binary search would do. However, k can be much smaller than n.

Comment: Did you have any thoughts on how to solve this? Here's a hint: Trace a normal binary search that finds `k`. Now, what happens if you approach `k` from the opposite direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Let's check the elements `a[1], a[2], a[4], ...` and so on(indices are powers of 2) until we the one which is greater than or equal to x. This step requires `O(log k)` operations(because we stop when we find the first power of two that is greater than or equal to `k`, which is at most `2 ^ (log(k) + 1)`).
2. Now we have a range that contains at most `2 * k - 1` elements. So we can apply standard binary search. It requires `O(log (2 * k - 1)) = O(log k)` operations.

Thus, the total time complexity is `O(log k).`

Comment: Thank you! With the tip from beaker I got to 1. and 2. filled in the rest.